# How to read/write a Rails ActiveRecord datetime field using Ecto?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm in the process of rewriting an API written in Rails to Elixir using Phoenix Framework.

The main website uses Rails, and will continue to use Rails. However I want the API to use Elixir.

I need to be able to read the `created_at` field from my Elixir API project.

```
defmodule Example.Recipe do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "recipes" do
    field :name, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :slug, :string
    field :created_at ???datetime?
  end
end
```

How can I read the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields properly from my Elixir API?

I know Ecto uses `Ecto.DateTime` but is that compatible?

Answer (score 4):

First of all Ecto uses an `inserted_at` column for tracking when a record is first inserted into the database, Rails uses `created_at`.

You should over-ride the inserted-at column name:

In an Ecto schema definition, timestamps accepts options specifying alternative column names for inserted_at and updated_at.

change:

Change the timestamps definition in web/models/your_model.ex from:

```
schema "your_model" do
  field :login, :string

  timestamps()
end
```

to

```
schema "your_model" do
  field :login, :string

  timestamps inserted_at: :created_at
end
```

to do this globally look https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-schema-attributes

```
def model do
  quote do
    use Ecto.Schema
    @timestamps_opts inserted_at: :created_at

    import Ecto
    import Ecto.Changeset
    import Ecto.Query
  end
end
```

further [references of migration](http://haughtcodeworks.com/blog/software-development/ecto-schemas-on-rails/)